# I am trying to use twitter's V2.0 api for a python tweepy bot. But I keep getting the forbidden error

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

This code keeps returning the 403 forbidden error. I have no clue how to fix this because all of the other examples I've looked at are for the v1.0 API. It says I need "Elevated access" to use this endpoint but I should be able to post a tweet with the essential access I have now. This is confusing and I would love some help!

```py
import tweepy
consumer_key = 'consumer_key'
consumer_secret = 'consumer_secret'
access_token = 'access_token'
access_token_secret = 'access_token_secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status("first tweet")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tweepy.Client` to access API v2 (not `tweepy.API`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client( consumer_key= "<your consumer/API key - see step 1>",
                        consumer_secret= "<your consumer/API secret - see step 1>",
                        access_token= "<your access token key - see step 1>",
                        access_token_secret= "<your access token secret - see step 1>")

#construct the tweet text
tweet_text =  f"Hello World" 

#Fire off the tweet!
response = client.create_tweet( tweet_text )
```

You can see full step by step article here:
https://pythonhowtoprogram.com/how-to-build-a-twitter-bot-with-python-and-twitter-api-v2/